# Is it possible to sync zoom between two scatter highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to achieve two things.

1 - In the above image, imagine that the top part does not exist to begin with. If the user were to click on any point on the bottom chart, I want the top chart to be created with a magnified view. And if the bottom part is clicked and dragged, the top part should follow that.

2 - If the bottom chart were zoomed in, I want the top chart to also be zoomed in. Ex: If bottom was 1x and top was 2x, if I zoom bottom by 2x, top should now be 4x.

Are these possible with highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that behavior is easily achievable in Highcharts. All you need to do is to use `Axis.afterSetExtremes` and  `Point.click` event callback function to create or update another chart with proper axis extremes. For example:

```
var chart1,
  scale = 4;

function createOrUpdateDetail() {
  var isPointClick = !this.lin2log,
    chart = this.chart || this.series.chart,
    xMin = chart.xAxis[0].min,
    xMax = chart.xAxis[0].max,
    xRange = xMax - xMin,
    xCenter = (xMax + xMin) / 2,
    yMin = chart.yAxis[0].min,
    yMax = chart.yAxis[0].max,
    yRange = yMax - yMin,
    yCenter = (yMax + yMin) / 2,
    calcXMin,
    calcXMax,
    calcYMin,
    calcYMax;

  if (isPointClick) {
    xCenter = this.x;
    yCenter = this.y;
  }

  calcXMin = xCenter - xRange / scale;
  calcXMax = xCenter + xRange / scale;
  calcYMin = yCenter - yRange / scale;
  calcYMax = yCenter + yRange / scale;

  if (!chart1) {
    chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: this.series.options.data
      }],
      xAxis: {
        min: calcXMin,
        max: calcXMax,
      },
      yAxis: {
        endOnTick: false,
        startOnTick: false,
        min: calcYMin,
        max: calcYMax
      }
    });

  } else {
    chart1.update({
      xAxis: {
        min: calcXMin,
        max: calcXMax,
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: calcYMin,
        max: calcYMax
      }
    });
  }
}

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    panning: true,
    panKey: 'shift'
  },
  yAxis: {
    endOnTick: false,
    startOnTick: false,
  },
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: createOrUpdateDetail
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [...],
    point: {
      events: {
        click: createOrUpdateDetail
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4982/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: This help the charts to sync, thanks. However the magnified chart only updates when a data point on the bottom chart is clicked. How do I make it update when a region (rectangular) is clicked and dragged around? The main use case would be mobile so selecting individual points would be difficult.

Comment: Hi @mismaah, What do you exactly mean? Panning is enabled with `shift` key.

Comment: What I meant is when I click anywhere on the bottom chart, it should form a rectangle like in the image I provided. And whatever is in that rectangle will be shown in the top chart. Right now if I click on an empty space in the bottom chart, nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. You need to use `chart.events.click`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click function and draw a rectangle: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect